# Opencart - Add a product to cart using URL href

Tags: html, opencart2.x

The below URL currently adds a product through "product_id=30" to the shopping cart, but it does not add the quantity through "quantity=2" to the Opencart "cart" using the HTML href URL link as below.

I think that there may be a syntax problem, as it adds the product, but not the quantity. I have tried numerous syntax changes with the same result, ie, it adds the product with quantity of 1, even though quantity of two is specified in the URL. The code is a snippet from the product.tpl page in my Opencart v2.3.0.2 The product is a completely custom one.

```
<p>Add a product:
    <a href='index.php? route=checkout/cart/addToCart&amp;product_id=30&amp;quantity=2;'>
        Add to Cart 11
    </a>
</p>
```

There may be a syntax error which is causing the quantity not to be set at 2 in the cart on submission, or is there a better way of achieving the correct result. 
I would like the syntax to correctly send the product_id and quantity options correctly. 
It currently only send the product_id with a quantity of 1.
As Opencart also allows the URL to send a PHP array ($option)-which I haven't included in the URL, I would also like to be able to add this to the URL as well if possible.

Comment: I think it's messing up because of the `&amp;` .Try using only `&`. Also show us the rest of the code that submits the form

Comment: It is not in a form yet. At this stage I just want to understand how to load a product manually before I design the form. I have tried with just the & with the same result.

Comment: try this: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=185378#p678284